# Query is executed but no data is displayed - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am basically trying to pull a policy's synopsis that is under a certain institution that has a certain policy type and it must be the most recent policy.

I have written out a SQL query and when executing there is no error, however it is not pulling any data when there should be at least one data retrieved.

Below is my query:

```
select synopsis
from policy p
     left outer join institution_has_policy ihp
          on p.policy_id = ihp.policy_id
     left outer join institution i 
          on i.institution_id = ihp.institution_id   
where p.policy_type_id = 5  
      and i.institution_name = 'SSgA Funds Management, Inc.'
      and current_as_of_date = (select max(current_as_of_date) from policy p);
```

Is my sql statement correct?

Comment: I would say something in your where is not correct. Take the statements out until your item is there then that narrows down where your problem is. I would say either in institution name or your date.

Comment: Query looks fine. Disect it and run parts at a time, starting with just policy.

Comment: I did as you suggested, it will run and display data until i re-insert the last where clause (currenet_as_of_date) then the data does not display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select synopsis
from policy p left outer join
     institution_has_policy ihp
     on p.policy_id = ihp.policy_id left outer join
     institution i 
     on i.institution_id = ihp.institution_id   
where p.policy_type_id = 5 and
      i.institution_name = 'SSgA Funds Management, Inc.'
      current_as_of_date = (select max(current_as_of_date) from policy p);
```

No data is returned because the maximum as of date doesn't correspond to the policy and institution name.  If you want only one row returned, then you can use `order by` and `limit` to get the latest:

```
select synopsis
from policy p left outer join
     institution_has_policy ihp
     on p.policy_id = ihp.policy_id left outer join
     institution i 
     on i.institution_id = ihp.institution_id   
where p.policy_type_id = 5 and
      i.institution_name = 'SSgA Funds Management, Inc.'
order by current_as_of_date desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect, as it's highly possible that the policy you selected won't be the actually most recent policy(of all, not of all the filtered ones). You can try deleting the date constraint, order it by date and select only the first row (LIMIT 1).

Comment: Oh, so my policy is being filtered incorrectly. So right now my sql statement is looking for a policy type of 5, but at the same time looking for ANY policy type with the most current date. which is why is not showing any data. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely. You'd need to repeat entire query in the (SELECT MAX(date) ....) for it to work this way. Using ordering and LIMIT 1 is a better way of doing that, though.